# Google Play: Long review times and hot fixes

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

When pushing app on Google Play Console in the Beta release section, some apps are reviewed within the hour, and any consecutive updates after that seems to have a 24 hour review time if I try to push updates too fast. Is there a way to minimize the review times to push "hot fixes" after an update has been pushed recently?

I have tried timmed publishing but the long review wait still applies for fast consecutive updates

Answer (score 1):

The situation appears to have precipitated, most probably with the COVID situation. Many users are pending for 30 days.

There is a hot discussion here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/35061212?hl=en

I tried to write to Google after 20 days of waits without any answer.